# Promoted links don't work with link of the file directory with a new tab

Tags: promoted-links

I have added a link of a files directory on the link location field in the promoted links. It doesn't work if the launch behavior is "new tab" but it works when "in page navigation". I want it to open in a new tab in windows explorer. How can I make it work?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2013 on-prem or Office 365? Have you tried it in different browsers?